# Installing phpMyAdmin on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

After installing phpMyAdmin on Amazon Linux using these commands...:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

... I have tried the steps described in this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/aronwoost/1105007) (referred to in previous StackOverflow Answers), but do get the following **error message** after issuing the command

`sudo chmod 0700 /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`: `File or Directory not found`.

How can I get phpMyAdmin running on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install phpmyadmin rpm package by yum command to enabling epel repositories

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin
```

You'll then have to change the phpMyAdmin config file to allow access from your IP.

Oh and you probably need to change your `sudo` command to be case sensitive. Double check your filename, but on my system it would be

```
sudo chmod 0700 /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

When I first tried to install phpMyAdmin on Amazon Linux, I got some trouble; even though, I had already using epel-release options.

What I did was:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

I got error

> No package phpmyadmin available.

If you got the same error you could try

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

then

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

should works.

As previous post said, you might need update the conf of phpmyadmin on Apache for public access. After

```
sudo chmod 0700 /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

You should update the config

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
 # Apache 2.2
 Order Deny,Allow
 Allow from All
 #Deny from All
 #Allow from 127.0.0.1
 #Allow from ::1
</IfModule>
```

then you should be able to access phpMyAdmin by http://domainname.com/phpMyAdmin now.

Reference:

- [How To Install and Secure phpMyAdmin on a CentOS 6.4 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-a-centos-6-4-vps)
- [Allowing network access to PHPMyAdmin](https://squeezesetup.wordpress.com/allowing-network-access-to-phpmyadmin/)
- [Install phpMyAdmin 4.3.10 on Fedora 21/20, CentOS/RHEL 6.6/5.11](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-phpmyadmin-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) in the Amazon EC2 documentation that covers installing a LAMP web server stack on Amazon Linux. One of the optional procedures in that topic includes [installing phpMyAdmin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html#d0e4129).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline